# Appropriate Loaders to handle community react native packages

Tags: javascript, react-native, babeljs

I am trying to use a [react native multi-slider](https://github.com/ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider#installation), but receive an error when compiling

```html
/node_modules/@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider/MultiSlider.js 18:22
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (18:22)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
| export default class MultiSlider extends React.Component {
>   static defaultProps = {
|     values: [0],
|     onValuesChangeStart: () => {},
```

I am a bit confused at where you specify a loader for the desired file. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I was able to solve it:

Adding the following underneath the "web" key in app.json:

```
"build": { "babel": { "include": [ "@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider" ] }}
```

Taken from https://github.com/akveo/react-native-ui-kitten/issues/996#issuecomment-790975093